# java.util.Map$Entry class file not found

Tags: java, eclipse

I recently updated Java to jre1.8.0_31 and Eclipse no longer will build my project.  It fails with a message that java.util.Map$Entry class file cannot be found.

Comment: Which OS are you using? The JAVA_HOME variable it's properly configured!?

Comment: It would shock me if that class really isn't there

Comment: did you update your project build path to point the new JDK installation ?

Comment: I am using Windows 7 Home Premium Service Pack 1 for the operating system.

Comment: Can someone tell me where the Map$Entry class file should normally be found?

Answer (score 0):

`java.util.Map$Entry` is a standard class in the JDK. In some circumstances it is in a file called `rt.jar` beneath `JAVA_HOME` but you should never have to add it yourself.

I am surprised that this is the only thing that is missing for you, there should be lots of other things missing too.

You should verify that your JDK is set up correctly under your preferences, and your project build path.

It's almost certain that the location of your JDK changed and Eclipse needs to be informed of this.

Also clean your project (right-click on top folder in project view, select 'clean'). Might be some stale files hanging around.

*Actually*, reviewing your question one final thing comes to mind, you say you updated your **JRE**. This is not the same thing as a **JDK**. You should install the [1.8 JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) also.

Comment: I have made sure that both the JDK and JRE are up-to-date.  I have looked at the JRE System Library pointed to by the build path in Eclipse and in particular I have looked for the java.util.Map$Entry.class and it doesn't seem to be there.  As a point of curiosity, the class name Map$Entry is peculiar because of the $ sign in it--not illegal but not common.  I'm still missing something, however your comments have been helpful.

Comment: the `$` denotes it as an inner class.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification about the $ punctuation.  With that in mind I looked again for the java.util.Map$Entry class in rt.jar using Eclipse's Project Explorer.  There is an entry for java.util.Map.Entry as a child element of java.util.Map in the resource tree but the entry appears with a question mark icon next to it.  I assume that this means that the resource  is missing (Eclipse help was no help in answering this question).

Comment: I'd be suspicious that maybe your JDK's are somehow mixed up. If lets say eclipse was still using javac from 1.7 let's say, against the 1.8 rt.jar this is the kind of thing I'd expect to see ...

Comment: This problem is apparently solved when I upgraded to Eclipse Luna.  Thanks everyone for your help on this.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue, below solution worked for me

add below dependency in parent pom file

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.7</version> <!-- 1.5 dint work for me -->
</plugin>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.3</version>
</plugin>           
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
<version>1.8.6</version>
</plugin>
```